# Set interval in steps - every step should be longer

Tags: javascript, setinterval

what i want to achieve is to setInterval and check condition - first time after one second, second time - after 3s, third time - after 5s and so on

1. check after 1s
2. next check after 1 + 2s = 3s
3. next check after 1 + 2s + 2s = 5s

How to achieve something like this?

```
     const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(externalWindow.location.href);
      const code = params.get('code');

      if (code) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        externalWindow.close();
      }

    }, 1000);
```

Comment: interval is wring thing, timeouts would be better

Answer (score 3):

You should use `setTimeout` instead, and increment `+= 2000` the initial delay each time.

```js
let timeout = setTimeout(
  function check(delay) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(externalWindow.location.href);
    const code = params.get('code');

    if (code)
      externalWindow.close();
    else {
      delay += 2000;
      timeout = setTimeout(check, delay, delay);
    }
  },
  1000,
  1000
);
```

You don't strictly need the `timeout` variable there, but it's handy if you want to `clearTimeout(timeout)` at any point outside that function expression.

Comment: This doesn't increase the timeout in the manner prescribed. You may need an outside function to do that. Did you intend to duplicate `1000` in the second and third args?

Comment: @isherwood by standard definition, both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` accept extra arguments that is the delay which, in this case, will be 1000, then 3000, then 5000, and so on ... https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#timers

Answer (score 0):

So can you tell me what is wrong in my code?

```
checkCode = (externalWindow) => {

    let retry = true;
    const params = new URLSearchParams(externalWindow.location.href);
    const code = params.get('code');

    if(code){
        console.log('code and stop loop');
        retry = false;
    }

    if (retry){
        console.log('retry');
        setTimeout(() => this.checkCode(externalWindow), 2000);
    }

  }
```

It is executed only once